# When to use imshow over pcolormesh

Tags: python, matplotlib, imshow

I often find myself needing to create heatmap-style visualizations in Python with matplotlib.  Matplotlib provides several functions which apparently do the same thing.  `pcolormesh` is recommended instead of `pcolor` but what is the difference (from a practical point of view as a data plotter) between `imshow` and `pcolormesh`?  What are the pros/cons of using one over the other?  In what scenarios would one or the other be a clear winner?

Answer (score 69, accepted):

Fundamentally, `imshow` assumes that all data elements in your array are to be rendered at the same size, whereas `pcolormesh`/`pcolor` associates elements of the data array with rectangular elements whose size may vary over the rectangular grid.

If your mesh elements are uniform, then `imshow` with interpolation set to "nearest" will look very similar to the default `pcolormesh` display (without the optional `X` and `Y` args). The obvious differences are that the `imshow` y-axis will be inverted (w.r.t. `pcolormesh`) and the aspect ratio is maintained, although those characteristics can be altered to look like the `pcolormesh` output as well.

From a practical point of view, `pcolormesh` is more convenient if you want to visualize the data array as cells, particularly when the rectangular mesh is non-uniform or when you want to plot the boundaries/edges of the cells. Otherwise, `imshow` is more convenient if you have a fixed cell size, want to maintain aspect ratio, want control over pixel interpolation, or want to specify RGB values directly.

Comment: +1 Just to add a bit: The aspect and flipping of the y-axis are easily controlled with keyword arguments to imshow (`aspect='auto'` and `origin='lower'` respectively).  In addition to what you mentioned, other major differences are: speed (`imshow` is much more efficient), the ability/inability to display the cell edges (`pcolor`/`pcolormesh` can, `imshow` can't), and the centering of the cells (`pcolormesh` aligns the cells on their edges, while `imshow` aligns them on their centers. This is controlled by the `extent` kwarg or using x & y arguments to `pcolormesh`.)

Comment: Also, `pcolormesh` isn't limited to just rectangular cells.  They can actually be any quadrilateral if you pass in the `x`, `y`, and `z` parameters.

Comment: Thanks for the additional info. I suspected `imshow` is faster but didn't bother to test that. Just to clarify, when you say `z` parameter, I assume you mean the `C` parameter (i.e., `pcolormesh` can't generate a 3D mesh).

Comment: Yeah, I mean `C` rather than `z`, though that wasn't clear at all from my comment.

Comment: Do you know if there is a blog post out there with visual examples comparing `imshow` and `pcolormesh`? Thanks!

Comment: `pcolormesh` also works nicely when one of your axis is a `datetime`. `imshow` doesn't like this and you have to convert to a pure numeric time representation.

Comment: @tommy.carstensen Check out this link: http://thomas-cokelaer.info/blog/2014/05/matplotlib-difference-between-pcolor-pcolormesh-and-imshow/

Comment: @blalterman Thanks! The page reads: "the main important difference is that pcolormesh is much faster".

Comment: just to make it clear: `pcolor` is slower than `pcolormesh`, which is itself slower than `imshow` (at least on Matplotlib 2.2.0).