# imshow non unifrom matrix bin size

Tags: matplotlib, imshow

I am trying to create an image with imshow, but the bins in my matrix are not equal.
For example the following matrix

```
C = [[1,2,2],[2,3,2],[3,2,3]]
```

is for `X = [1,4,8]` and for `Y = [2,4,9]`
I know I can just do `xticks` and `yticks`, but I want the axis to be equal..This means that I will need the squares which build the imshow to be in different sizes.
Is it possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This seems like a job for `pcolormesh`.
From [When to use imshow over pcolormesh](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21169703/4720935):

> Fundamentally, imshow assumes that all data elements in your array are
>   to be rendered at the same size, whereas pcolormesh/pcolor associates
>   elements of the data array with rectangular elements whose size may
>   vary over the rectangular grid.

`pcolormesh` plots a matrix as cells, and take as argument the x and y coordinates of the cells, which allows you to draw each cell in a different size.

I assume the X and Y of your example data are meant to be the size of the cells. So I converted them in coordinates with:

```
xSize=[1,4,9]
ySize=[2,4,8]
x=np.append(0,np.cumsum(xSize)) # gives [ 0  1  5 13]
y=np.append(0,np.cumsum(ySize)) # gives [ 0  2  6 15]
```

Then if you want a similar behavior as `imshow`, you need to revert the y axis.

```
c=np.array([[1,2,2],[2,3,2],[3,2,3]])
plt.pcolormesh(x,-y,c)
```

Which gives us:

[image: pcolor to replace imshow]