# matplotlib pcolormesh creates data artifacts

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm plotting data using the `matplotlib` functions `pcolormesh` and `imshow` and when I use `pcolormesh` it produces artifacts where it seems to slide some of the data around:

[image: pcolormesh]

whereas `imshow` does not:

[image]

I was able to produce an example that has the same artifacting

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

data = pd.DataFrame({'x':np.random.normal(loc=0.5, size=5000)
                     , 'y':np.random.normal(loc=0.5, size=5000)
                     , 'z':np.random.normal(loc=0.5, size=5000)})

data_pivot = data.pivot(index='x', columns='y', values='z')
x = data_pivot.index.values
y = data_pivot.columns.values
z = data_pivot.values
masked_data = np.ma.masked_invalid(z)
```

which produces the following figures like so:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, figsize=(8,8))
ax.pcolormesh(x, y, masked_data)
```

[image]

Where do these artifacts come from? There isn't anything wrong with the data as far as I can tell since the original data and the made up data produce the same result.

Comment: Hm. This answer is hinting a reason: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21166679/when-to-use-imshow-over-pcolormesh, but it still looks like a bug to me.

Comment: That's what I'm afraid of. This is ultimately for plotting using `basemap` but there is [no issues reported like what I'm describing](https://github.com/matplotlib/basemap/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=pcolormesh). Nor did I find any in the `matplotlib` [issue tracker](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=pcolormesh). That doesn't mean there isn't any though.

Comment: I submitted a bug report and it seems like maybe my data is not correctly formatted. However I am not sure if this is the case. [link to bug report](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/6331)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is, my data was not shaped correctly. `pcolormesh` expects the input array to have the right number of columns and rows, even if those columns and rows are full of NaNs. Thus when it finds a "gap" in the data it fills it with the last known value. The artifacts are not artifacts but gaps in the data. In my original example I had assumed `imshow` to be correct when in fact it is not accounting for these gaps.

Comment: How did you fix it? is there a way to fill the gaps with a chosen value?