# matplotlib pcolormesh artifact

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I have [a file](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/54733883/surface.txt) describing a grid over the earth with the format:

```
lon1,lat1,value1
lon2,lat2,value2
...
```

I wrote the following script in order to plot it:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import numpy.ma as ma


lons,lats,grads=np.loadtxt('surface.txt',dtype=str).T
lons=lons.astype(float).reshape(715,252)
lats=lats.astype(float).reshape(715,252)
grads[grads=='NA'] = np.nan
grads=grads.astype(float).reshape(715,252)
grads=ma.masked_where(np.isnan(grads),grads)

fig=plt.figure()
ax=plt.gca()
im=ax.pcolormesh(lons,lats,grads)
plt.colorbar(im)
plt.title('pcolormesh')
```

[image]

everything is working fine except for the artifact appearing at around `y=-5`.

I have plotted the same data with with `contourf` to make sure it's not in the data and the artifact is gone but I want to do it using [`pcolormesh`](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.pcolormesh).

```
fig=plt.figure()
ax=plt.gca()
im=ax.contourf(lons,lats,grads)
plt.colorbar(im)
plt.title('contourf')
```

[image]

I've found this related question but can't figure out a solution from it:
 [matplotlib pcolormesh creates data artifacts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36799379/matplotlib-pcolormesh-creates-data-artifacts)

Comment: Can you slice your data to a smaller rectangle, and still get this effect?

Comment: Your problem is that latitudes and longitudes are cyclic, and your largest longitude value wraps around

Comment: It's also worth noting that in this case `ax.pcolormesh(lons,lats,grads)` is the same as `ax.pcolormesh(lons,lats,grads[:-1,:-1])`, ie the last row and column of your data are being discarded

Comment: @Eric you are right about **"Your problem is that latitudes and longitudes are cyclic"** but I still can't figure out how to use that information to solve this problem

Comment: Your x coordinates look like `[-30, 0, 30, .., 240, 270, -60]` (for example). That red box is `pcolor` drawing a rectangle from `270` to `-60`

Comment: @Eric you were right I sorted the longitudes to be continuous and it worked.  I think this is worth a "real" answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following the comment by @Eric

> Your problem is that latitudes and longitudes are cyclic, and your
>   largest longitude value wraps around

I've changed the code to reorder the longitudes before plotting so that they are continuous.

```
data=np.loadtxt('surface.txt',dtype=str)
lons=data.T[0].astype(float)

#reorder the data so that lons smaller than 180 are before larger ones
data=np.hstack((data[lons<180].T,data[lons>=180].T))

lons,lats,grads=data
lons=lons.astype(float).reshape(715,252)
lats=lats.astype(float).reshape(715,252)
grads[grads=='NA']=np.nan
grads=grads.astype(float).reshape(715,252)

grads=ma.masked_where(np.isnan(grads),grads)

fig=plt.figure()
ax=plt.gca()
im=ax.pcolormesh(lons,lats,grads)
plt.colorbar(im)
plt.title('pcolormesh')
```

[image]