# Python matplotlib black and white grid with squares

Tags: python, matplotlib

does anyone know how to make a grid using matplotlib which essentially looks like a chess board.
It needs to have black and white squares.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10194482/custom-matplotlib-plot-chess-board-like-table-with-colored-cells) help you?

Comment: If you plot [this array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2169478/how-to-make-a-checkerboard-in-numpy) with `plt.imshow()`, it'll look like a chess board.

Comment: Thank you both very much for the answers. They both work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An easy way to do this is to set a 2d matrix with elements 0,1 for example as your chessboard. Then use imshow from matplotlib.pyplot and use the gray scale for it.

This is a simple example of a 4 squares chessboard

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
a = [[0,1],[1,0]]
plt.imshow(a,cmap='gray')
plt.show()
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, do you by any chance know how to get lines between the squares on the grid?

Comment: I never tried that myself but think there are some good advices here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38973868/adjusting-gridlines-and-ticks-in-matplotlib-imshow