# How to MatPlotLib plot and then add different axes?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to plot the solution of a PDE from (0, 0) to (10, 10). The solution is given in a 20 by 20 matrix.

Here is my code:

```
plt.figure()
plt.title(f"Temperature at t = 100")
plt.xlabel("x")
plt.ylabel("y")

plt.pcolormesh(U[-1], cmap=plt.cm.jet)
plt.colorbar()
```

[image]

So I would like the same plot, but the axis should be from 0 to 10. Can I add a second axis that goes from 0 to 10 and then hide the current axis? Is it possible to achieve this without `plt.subplots()` because I would like to animate this figure  (`animation.FuncAnimation(plt.figure(), animate, frames=range(0, max_iter))`, where animate is a function containing the code above)?

Comment: @BigBen Because I am trying to animate this figure: `animation.FuncAnimation(plt.figure(), animate, frames=range(0, max_iter))`, where animate is a function containing the code in my question.

Comment: Are you required to use `pcolormesh` for this? Using `imshow` I can do exactly what you are asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution `U` contains the color values and array shape information, but don't explicitly define the bounded x/y-values as you've pointed out. To do this with `pcolormesh`, we just need to change the values according to the `axes()` class, as so (using a random dataset):

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

U = np.random.rand(20,20)
print(U.shape)

plt.figure()
ax=plt.axes()
plt.title(f"Temperature at t = 100")
plt.xlabel("x")
plt.ylabel("y")
plt.pcolormesh(U, cmap=plt.cm.jet)
x=y=np.linspace(0,10,11) # Define a min and max with regular spacing
ax.set_xticks(np.linspace(0,20,11)) # Ensure same number of x,y ticks
ax.set_yticks(np.linspace(0,20,11))
ax.set_xticklabels(x.astype(int)) # Change values according to the grid
ax.set_yticklabels(y.astype(int))
plt.colorbar()
plt.show()
```

[image: pcolormesh]

Alternatively, we can explicitly define these using the `extent=[<xmin>,<xmax>,<ymin>,<ymax>]` option in `imshow`, as seen below:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

U = np.random.rand(20,20)
print(U.shape) # Displays (20,20)

plt.figure()
plt.title(f"Temperature at t = 100")
plt.xlabel("x")
plt.ylabel("y")
plt.imshow(U, origin='lower', aspect='auto', extent = [0,10,0,10], cmap=plt.cm.jet)
plt.colorbar()
plt.show()
```

[image: Output of imshow]

For further reading on which to use, `pcolormesh` or `imshow`, there is a good thread about it here: [When to use imshow over pcolormesh?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21166679/when-to-use-imshow-over-pcolormesh)