# Plot correlation matrix using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, data-visualization, information-visualization

I have a data set with huge number of features, so analysing the correlation matrix has become very difficult. I want to plot a correlation matrix which we get using `dataframe.corr()` function from pandas library. Is there any built-in function provided by the pandas library to plot this matrix?

Comment: Related answers can be found here [Making heatmap from pandas DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12286607/python-making-heatmap-from-dataframe)

Comment: [Seaborn clustermap](https://seaborn.pydata.org/examples/structured_heatmap.html) might also be an interesting way to visualise the correlation matrix: `sns_plot = sns.clustermap(dataframe.corr(), cmap="rocket_r")`

Answer (score 465, accepted):

You can use [`pyplot.matshow()`](http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/matshow.html)  from `matplotlib`:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.matshow(dataframe.corr())
plt.show()
```

---

Edit:

In the comments was a request for how to change the axis tick labels. Here's a deluxe version that is drawn on a bigger figure size, has axis labels to match the dataframe, and a colorbar legend to interpret the color scale.

I'm including how to adjust the size and rotation of the labels, and I'm using a figure ratio that makes the colorbar and the main figure come out the same height.

---

EDIT 2:
As the df.corr() method ignores non-numerical columns, `.select_dtypes(['number'])` should be used when defining the x and y labels to avoid an unwanted shift of the labels (included in the code below).

```
f = plt.figure(figsize=(19, 15))
plt.matshow(df.corr(), fignum=f.number)
plt.xticks(range(df.select_dtypes(['number']).shape[1]), df.select_dtypes(['number']).columns, fontsize=14, rotation=45)
plt.yticks(range(df.select_dtypes(['number']).shape[1]), df.select_dtypes(['number']).columns, fontsize=14)
cb = plt.colorbar()
cb.ax.tick_params(labelsize=14)
plt.title('Correlation Matrix', fontsize=16);
```

[image: correlation plot example]

Comment: I must be missing something: `AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'matshow'`

Comment: @TomRussell Did you do `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt`?

Comment: do you know how to display the actual column names on the plot?

Comment: @jrjc Hi thanks for the answer, I wonder how can I move the upper x-axis labels to the bottom because the length of my attributes are a big long

Comment: @Cecilia I had  resolved  this  matter by  changing  the **rotation** parameter to **90**

Comment: With columns names longer than those, the x labels will look a bit off, in my case it was confusing as they looked shifted by one tick. Adding `ha="left"` to the `plt.xticks` call solved this problem, in case anyone has it as well :) described in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28615887/how-to-move-a-ticks-label-in-matplotlib

Comment: best way to save plots with all the x and y ticks ?

Answer (score 436):

If your main goal is to visualize the correlation matrix, rather than creating a plot per se, the convenient `pandas` [styling options](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/style.html) is a viable built-in solution:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

rs = np.random.RandomState(0)
df = pd.DataFrame(rs.rand(10, 10))
corr = df.corr()
corr.style.background_gradient(cmap='coolwarm')
# 'RdBu_r', 'BrBG_r', & PuOr_r are other good diverging colormaps
```

[image]

Note that this needs to be in a backend that supports rendering HTML, such as the JupyterLab Notebook.

---

## Styling

You can easily limit the digit precision (this is now `.format(precision=2)` in pandas 2.*):

```
corr.style.background_gradient(cmap='coolwarm').set_precision(2)
```

[image]

Or get rid of the digits altogether if you prefer the matrix without annotations:

```
corr.style.background_gradient(cmap='coolwarm').set_properties(**{'font-size': '0pt'})
```

[image]

The styling documentation also includes instructions of more advanced styles, such as how to change the display of the cell the mouse pointer is hovering over.

---

## Time comparison

In my testing, `style.background_gradient()` was 4x faster than `plt.matshow()` and 120x faster than `sns.heatmap()` with a 10x10 matrix. Unfortunately it doesn't scale as well as `plt.matshow()`: the two take about the same time for a 100x100 matrix, and `plt.matshow()` is 10x faster for a 1000x1000 matrix.

---

## Saving

There are a few possible ways to save the stylized dataframe:

- Return the HTML by appending the `render()` method and then write the output to a file.
- Save as an `.xslx` file with conditional formatting by appending the `to_excel()` method.
- [Combine with imgkit to save a bitmap](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50097322/2166823)
- Take a screenshot (like I have done here).

---

## Normalize colors across the entire matrix (pandas >= 0.24)

By setting `axis=None`, it is now possible to compute the colors based on the entire matrix rather than per column or per row:

```
corr.style.background_gradient(cmap='coolwarm', axis=None)
```

[image]

---

## Single corner heatmap

Since many people are reading this answer I thought I would add a tip for how to only show one corner of the correlation matrix. I find this easier to read myself, since it removes the redundant information.

```
# Fill diagonal and upper half with NaNs
mask = np.zeros_like(corr, dtype=bool)
mask[np.triu_indices_from(mask)] = True
corr[mask] = np.nan
(corr
 .style
 .background_gradient(cmap='coolwarm', axis=None, vmin=-1, vmax=1)
 .highlight_null(color='#f1f1f1')  # Color NaNs grey
 .format(precision=2))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! You definitely need a diverging palette ```import seaborn as sns
corr = df.corr()
cm = sns.light_palette("green", as_cmap=True)
cm = sns.diverging_palette(220, 20, sep=20, as_cmap=True)
corr.style.background_gradient(cmap=cm).set_precision(2)```

Comment: @stallingOne Good point, I shouldn't have included negative values in the example, I might change that later.

Just for reference for people reading this, you don't need to create a custom divergent cmap with seaborn (although the one in the comment above looks pretty slick), you can also use the built-in divergent cmaps from matplotlib, e.g. `corr.style.background_gradient(cmap='coolwarm')`. There is currently no way to center the cmap on a specific value, which can be a good idea with divergent cmaps.

Comment: Is there a way to get `xticks` and `yticks` as column names rather than number ?

Comment: @Hayat By default, the column names and index from the data frame are displayed so you can change these names using pandas `rename` https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename.html

Comment: when I do `dataframe.columns` it is shows proper cols but when I call `df.corr()` and plot `ticks` are converted to numbers.

Comment: @Hayat Please post a new question about this and include the code your are running. Feel free to link it here and I can have a look.

Comment: What does it mean when a column's color is black in a cmap='coolwarm' plot? @joelostblom Here's an example: https://gist.github.com/gumdropsteve/b483a739659e62009317df69bdc5de4a

Comment: @gumdropsteve It could be NaNs, but please ask a new question for this.

Comment: Thank you, that is cool. How to display these correlation heatmap in a loop to show multiple dataframe? this style can only work for one dataframe in jupyter notebook cell. Even in jupyter notebook cell, can I display multiple heatmap using loop? Thanks

Comment: @roudan You can use `from IPython.display import display` (or import `display_html`)and then `display(df)` in the loop. https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/generated/IPython.display.html#IPython.display.display

Comment: this is great, you can also set the colour limits manually, instead of using the data range, with e.g. `vmin=-1, vmax=1`

Comment: Avoid this method! Elements with same values can different colors.  Eg. look at the third plot: Colors are not symetrical with respect to the diagonal.

Comment: @Santiago You can control this with the `axis` keyword. See the section above on normalizing colors across the entire matrix rather than per row/column which is what you are referring to.

Comment: @joelostblom  you are right `axis=None` does the trick. Without that (the beggining of the answer), the colors do not correspond to the correlation matrix, but  instead to the gradients of its values in the rows/cols.

Comment: @joelostblom, thank you! If one wants to have a lower triangle with the diagonal, one can use `corr.where(mask, np.NAN)`.

Answer (score 128):

Seaborn's heatmap version:

```
import seaborn as sns
corr = dataframe.corr()
sns.heatmap(corr, 
            xticklabels=corr.columns.values,
            yticklabels=corr.columns.values)
```

Comment: Seaborn heatmap is fancy but it performs poor on large matrices.
matshow method of matplotlib is much faster.

Comment: Seaborn can automatically infer the ticklabels from the column names.

Comment: It seems that not all ticklabels are shown always if seaborn is left to automatically infer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50754471/seaborn-heatmap-not-displaying-all-xticks-and-yticks

Comment: Would be nice to also include normalizing the color from -1 to 1, otherwise the colors will span from the lowest correlation (can be anywhere) to highest correlation (1, on the diagonal).

Answer (score 108):

You can observe the relation between features either by drawing a heat map from seaborn or scatter matrix from pandas.

Scatter Matrix:

```
pd.scatter_matrix(dataframe, alpha = 0.3, figsize = (14,8), diagonal = 'kde');
```

If you want to visualize each feature's skewness as well - use seaborn pairplots.

```
sns.pairplot(dataframe)
```

Sns Heatmap:

```
import seaborn as sns

f, ax = pl.subplots(figsize=(10, 8))
corr = dataframe.corr()
sns.heatmap(corr,
    cmap=sns.diverging_palette(220, 10, as_cmap=True),
    vmin=-1.0, vmax=1.0,
    square=True, ax=ax)
```

The output will be a correlation map of the features. i.e. see the below example.

[image]

The correlation between grocery and detergents is high. Similarly:

##### Pdoducts With High Correlation:

1. Grocery and Detergents.

##### Products With Medium Correlation:

1. Milk and Grocery
2. Milk and Detergents_Paper

##### Products With Low Correlation:

1. Milk and Deli
2. Frozen and Fresh.
3. Frozen and Deli.

From Pairplots: You can observe same set of relations from pairplots or scatter matrix. But from these we can say that whether the data is normally distributed or not.

[image]

Note: The above is same graph taken from the data, which is used to draw heatmap.

Comment: I think it should be .plt not .pl (if this is referring to matplotlib)

Comment: @ghukill Not neccessarily. He could have referred it as `from matplotlib import pyplot as pl`

Comment: how to set the boundary of the correlation between -1 to +1 always, in the correlation plot

Comment: Great answer. In case anyone has the error `AttributeError: module 'pandas' has no attribute 'scatter_matrix'`. Please see [this question for help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55394041/how-can-i-solve-module-pandas-has-no-attribute-scatter-matrix-error) tl;dr: Use `pd.plotting.scatter_matrix()`

Comment: Should be `pd.plotting.scatter_matrix(dataframe, alpha = 0.3, figsize = (14,8), diagonal = 'kde');` instead of `pd.scatter_matrix(dataframe, alpha = 0.3, figsize = (14,8), diagonal = 'kde');`

Answer (score 106):

Try this function, which also displays variable names for the correlation matrix:

```
def plot_corr(df,size=10):
    """Function plots a graphical correlation matrix for each pair of columns in the dataframe.

    Input:
        df: pandas DataFrame
        size: vertical and horizontal size of the plot
    """

    corr = df.corr()
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(size, size))
    ax.matshow(corr)
    plt.xticks(range(len(corr.columns)), corr.columns)
    plt.yticks(range(len(corr.columns)), corr.columns)
```

Comment: `plt.xticks(range(len(corr.columns)), corr.columns, rotation='vertical')` if you want vertical orientation of column names on x-axis

Comment: Another graphical thing, but adding a `plt.tight_layout()` might also be useful for long column names.

Answer (score 20):

For completeness, the simplest solution i know with [seaborn](https://seaborn.pydata.org/) as of late 2019, if one is using [Jupyter](https://jupyter.org/):

```
import seaborn as sns
sns.heatmap(dataframe.corr())
```

Answer (score 15):

Surprised to see no one mentioned more capable, interactive and easier to use alternatives.

### A) You can use plotly:

1. Just two lines and you get:
2. interactivity,
3. smooth scale,
4. colors based on whole dataframe instead of individual columns,
5. column names & row indices on axes,
6. zooming in,
7. panning,
8. built-in one-click ability to save it as a PNG format,
9. auto-scaling,
10. comparison on hovering,
11. bubbles showing values so heatmap still looks good and you can see
    values wherever you want:

```
import plotly.express as px
fig = px.imshow(df.corr())
fig.show()
```

[image]

### B) You can also use Bokeh:

All the same functionality with a tad much hassle. But still worth it if you do not want to opt-in for plotly and still want all these things:

```
from bokeh.plotting import figure, show, output_notebook
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource, LinearColorMapper
from bokeh.transform import transform
output_notebook()
colors = ['#d7191c', '#fdae61', '#ffffbf', '#a6d96a', '#1a9641']
TOOLS = "hover,save,pan,box_zoom,reset,wheel_zoom"
data = df.corr().stack().rename("value").reset_index()
p = figure(x_range=list(df.columns), y_range=list(df.index), tools=TOOLS, toolbar_location='below',
           tooltips=[('Row, Column', '@level_0 x @level_1'), ('value', '@value')], height = 500, width = 500)

p.rect(x="level_1", y="level_0", width=1, height=1,
       source=data,
       fill_color={'field': 'value', 'transform': LinearColorMapper(palette=colors, low=data.value.min(), high=data.value.max())},
       line_color=None)
color_bar = ColorBar(color_mapper=LinearColorMapper(palette=colors, low=data.value.min(), high=data.value.max()), major_label_text_font_size="7px",
                     ticker=BasicTicker(desired_num_ticks=len(colors)),
                     formatter=PrintfTickFormatter(format="%f"),
                     label_standoff=6, border_line_color=None, location=(0, 0))
p.add_layout(color_bar, 'right')

show(p)
```

[image]

Answer (score 14):

I think there are many good answers but I added this answer to those who need to deal with specific columns and to show a different plot.

```
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

rs = np.random.RandomState(0)
df = pd.DataFrame(rs.rand(18, 18))
df= df.iloc[: , [3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,17]].copy()
corr = df.corr()
plt.figure(figsize=(11,8))
sns.heatmap(corr, cmap="Greens",annot=True)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 13):

If you dataframe is `df` you can simply use:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

plt.figure(figsize=(15, 10))
sns.heatmap(df.corr(), annot=True)
```

Answer (score 12):

You can use imshow() method from matplotlib

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.style.use('ggplot')

plt.imshow(X.corr(), cmap=plt.cm.Reds, interpolation='nearest')
plt.colorbar()
tick_marks = [i for i in range(len(X.columns))]
plt.xticks(tick_marks, X.columns, rotation='vertical')
plt.yticks(tick_marks, X.columns)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 7):

statmodels graphics also gives a nice view of correlation matrix

```
import statsmodels.api as sm
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

corr = dataframe.corr()
sm.graphics.plot_corr(corr, xnames=list(corr.columns))
plt.show()
```

Comment: Note that this also shows column names, which is a big plus.

Answer (score 6):

When working with correlations between a large number of features I find it useful to cluster related features together.  This can be done with the seaborn [clustermap](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.clustermap.html) plot.

```
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

g = sns.clustermap(df.corr(), 
                   method = 'complete', 
                   cmap   = 'RdBu', 
                   annot  = True, 
                   annot_kws = {'size': 8})
plt.setp(g.ax_heatmap.get_xticklabels(), rotation=60);
```

[image]

The clustermap function uses [hierarchical clustering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hierarchical_clustering) to arrange relevant features together and produce the tree-like dendrograms.

There are two notable clusters in this plot:

1. `y_des` and `dew.point_des`
2. `irradiance`, `y_seasonal` and `dew.point_seasonal`

---

FWIW the meteorological data to generate this figure can be accessed with [this Jupyter notebook](https://github.com/makeyourownmaker/CambridgeTemperatureNotebooks/blob/main/notebooks/gradient_boosting.ipynb).

Answer (score 5):

Along with other methods it is also good to have pairplot which will give scatter plot for all the cases-

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
rs = np.random.RandomState(0)
df = pd.DataFrame(rs.rand(10, 10))
sns.pairplot(df)
```

Answer (score 3):

There are a lot of useful answers. I just want to add a way of visualizing the correlation matrix. Because sometimes the colors do not clear for you, [`heatmap`](https://github.com/jjguy/heatmap) library can plot a correlation matrix that displays square sizes for each correlation measurement.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from heatmap import corrplot

plt.figure(figsize=(15, 15))
corrplot(df.corr())
```

[image]

Comment: according to this package creators' website, it "requires the Python Imaging Library and Python 2.5+." It does not load if you have Python 3

Answer (score 2):

Form correlation matrix, in my case zdf is the dataframe which i need perform correlation matrix.

```
corrMatrix =zdf.corr()
corrMatrix.to_csv('sm_zscaled_correlation_matrix.csv');
html = corrMatrix.style.background_gradient(cmap='RdBu').set_precision(2).render()

# Writing the output to a html file.
with open('test.html', 'w') as f:
   print('<!DOCTYPE html><html lang="en"><head><meta charset="UTF-8"><meta name="viewport" content="width=device-widthinitial-scale=1.0"><title>Document</title></head><style>table{word-break: break-all;}</style><body>' + html+'</body></html>', file=f)
```

Then we can take screenshot. or convert html to an image file.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `heatmap()` from seaborn to see the correlation b/w different features:

```
import matplot.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

co_matrics=dataframe.corr()
plot.figure(figsize=(15,20))
sns.heatmap(co_matrix, square=True, cbar_kws={"shrink": .5})
```

Answer (score 1):

I would prefer to do it with Plotly because it's more interactive charts and it would be easier to understand. You can use the following snippet.

```
import plotly.express as px

def plotly_corr_plot(df,w,h):
    fig = px.imshow(df.corr())
    fig.update_layout(
        autosize=False,
        width=w,
        height=h,)
    fig.show()
```

Answer (score -1):

**Please check below readable code**

````
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.figure(figsize=(36, 26))
heatmap = sns.heatmap(df.corr(), vmin=-1, vmax=1, annot=True)
heatmap.set_title('Correlation Heatmap', fontdict={'fontsize':12}, pad=12)```

  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/I5SeR.png
````

Answer (score -2):

```
corrmatrix = df.corr()
corrmatrix *= np.tri(*corrmatrix.values.shape, k=-1).T
corrmatrix = corrmatrix.stack().sort_values(ascending = False).reset_index()
corrmatrix.columns = ['Признак 1', 'Признак 2', 'Корреляция']
corrmatrix[(corrmatrix['Корреляция'] >= 0.7) + (corrmatrix['Корреляция'] <= -0.7)]
drop_columns = corrmatrix[(corrmatrix['Корреляция'] >= 0.82) + (corrmatrix['Корреляция'] <= -0.7)]['Признак 2']
df.drop(drop_columns, axis=1, inplace=True)
corrmatrix[(corrmatrix['Корреляция'] >= 0.7) + (corrmatrix['Корреляция'] <= -0.7)]
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Add explanations to your code, explain why it's better than the accepted answer, and make sure to use English in the code.