# Seaborn heatmap not displaying all xticks and yticks

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

I have a pandas dataframe of shape (39, 67). When I plot it's `seaborn` heatmap, I don't get as many labels on the X and Y axes. `.get_xticklabels()` method also returns only 23 labels.

[image: Seaborn heatmap for dataframe]

`matplotlib` doesn't show any labels (only numbers) as well.

[image: Matpllotlib heatmap]

Both these heatmaps are for the same dataframe (39, 67).

Answer (score 76, accepted):

To ensure the labels are visible, you have to set the parameters `xticklabels`, `yticklabels` to `True`, like so.

```
import seaborn as sns 
sns.heatmap(dataframe, xticklabels=True, yticklabels=True)
```

[Here's](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.heatmap.html) the documentation for the `heatmap` function.

Comment: Setting `xticklabels` to `True`, only switches plotting on, but does not ensure that every label is displayed. To ensure this, set `xticklabels = 1` instead.

Comment: @MartijnVanAttekum Do you have a docs source, or more explanation? For me, only some showed without `xticklabels` specified, however they all showed whether I specified `xticklabels=True` or `xticklabels=1`.

Answer (score 5):

```
import seaborn as sns 
sns.heatmap(dataframe, xticklabels=1, yticklabels=1)
```

You may also play with `figsize=(7, 5)` to adjust the scale.

Comment: ConversionError: Failed to convert value(s) to axis units: Index(['A', ...

Answer (score 0):

The answers here didnt work for me so I followed the suggestions here.
Try opening a separate matplotlib window and tweak the parameters there,
[Python sns heatmap does not fully display x labels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71906295/python-sns-heatmap-does-not-fully-display-x-labels)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and this solved it:

- axes labels not showing properly:
  [image]

- after adjusting subplot bottom param:
[image]