# Python sns heatmap does not fully display x labels

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, plot, heatmap, figure

In visual studio python code, I am trying to create a heatmap for my data features. The feature name is sometimes long, and this causes the label on the x-axis to be partially visible sometimes (but not all of it). I tried rotation but this makes the ordering of the labels incorrect and results in some overlap between labels text. Below is my code and heatmap output. How to solve this issue?

```
pyplot.figure(figsize=(20,20))

g=sns.heatmap(df.corr(), vmin=df.corr().values.min(), 
              vmax=1, square=True, cmap="YlGnBu", linewidths=0.1, 
              annot=True, annot_kws={"fontsize":4},
              xticklabels=1, yticklabels=1) 

g.set_xticklabels(g.get_xticklabels(), fontsize = 7)
g.set_yticklabels(g.get_yticklabels(), rotation = 0, fontsize = 7)
pyplot.show()
```

[image]

I also would like to ask if there is a way to make the values in the cells more visible possibly by making it bold, because when I increase the font size, the values in the cells overlap.

Comment: if you use `%matplotlib` you get a separate window with the plot and you can tweak the margins with the settings, maybe you can set these too programmatically on the plot

Comment: Hi, I am not sure how to do that....If you have a code, it would be appreciated.

Comment: with the separate window can you see what you want after playing with the settings (margins, padding or whatever they call it)

Comment: Oh wait, I just found a way to control these....yes thank you!

Comment: will you let us all know how?

Comment: I just did not pay attention earlier that where the heatmap is displayed, there is a button in the bottom for controlling the margin and padding as you said....That's how I was able to adjust these and get the full visibility of the labels.