# python make correlation matrix

Tags: python, dataframe, correlation

I have one dataframe as below:

```
  combination      qmin      qmax      mean    median
0     003-124  0.014039  0.309451  0.165592  0.169842
0     014-017  0.992299  0.998932  0.996361  0.997515
0     014-018  0.798309  0.966721  0.903433  0.932848
0     014-019  0.798313  0.966721  0.903433  0.932848
```

.......................................................
This means the factor003 and factor124 correlation coefficient is 0.165592(column mean),etc. Now I want to get the big correlation matrix,inculding all the factors. How can I get this? Thanks.

Comment: Format your data and question properly.

Comment: What is factor003, factor124??

Comment: possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29432629/correlation-matrix-using-pandas

Comment: @KhalilAlHooti I have already calculated the correlation coefficient between factor003 and factor124. So it is no need to know what is factor003 or factor124. Thanks,