# How can I solve " module 'pandas' has no attribute 'scatter_matrix' " error?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I'm trying to run `pd.scatter_matrix()` function in Jupyter Notebook with my code below:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

# Load some data
iris = datasets.load_iris()
iris_df = pd.DataFrame(iris['data'], columns=iris['feature_names'])
iris_df['species'] = iris['target']

pd.scatter_matrix(iris_df, alpha=0.2, figsize=(10, 10))
plt.show()
```

But I'm getting
`AttributeError: module 'pandas' has no attribute 'scatter_matrix'`.
Even after executing `conda update pandas` and `conda update matplotlib` commands in Terminal, this is still occurring.

I executed `pd.__version__` command to check my pandas version and it's `'0.24.2'`. What could be the problem?

Comment: it's under `plotting`: see the [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.plotting.scatter_matrix.html?highlight=scatter#pandas.plotting.scatter_matrix) please check the api against your version

Answer (score 66, accepted):

This method is under `pandas.plotting` - [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/visualization.html#scatter-matrix-plot) and [`pandas.plotting.scatter_matrix`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.plotting.scatter_matrix.html):

```
from pandas.plotting import scatter_matrix

scatter_matrix(iris_df, alpha=0.2, figsize=(10, 10))
```

Comment: I'm just fresh in python but shouldn't pandas.plotting be already included in pandas? I'm running a tutorial right now where exactly the code in the question is given and I wondered, too, why it didn't work. But when using "from pandas.plotting ..." it works.
Nevertheless, I would like to know why the plotting command is so special it has to be imported manually?

Comment: Still getting error 'AttributeError: module 'pandas' has no attribute 'scatter_matrix''

Answer (score 22):

Another option is keeping only pandas import and rewriting the command `scatter_matrix`, like in the example below:

```
import pandas as pd

pd.plotting.scatter_matrix(iris_df, alpha=0.2, figsize=(10, 10))
```

Comment: Best answer. You don't need to reimport panda modules.

Answer (score 4):

Using

```
from pandas.plotting._misc import scatter_matrix
```

don't use `pd.scatter_matrix` or `pandas.scatter_matrix`
you can directly call `scatter_matrix`

e.g.

```
cmap = cm.get_cmap('gnuplot')
scatter = scatter_matrix(X, c = y, marker = 'o', s=40, hist_kwds={'bins':15}, 
    figsize=(9,9), cmap = cmap)
plt.suptitle('Scatter-matrix for each input variable')
plt.savefig('fruits_scatter_matrix')
plt.show()
```

Comment: Please read the [editing guide](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)

Answer (score 3):

Use:

```
from pandas.plotting import scatter_matrix
```

The code becomes:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from pandas.plotting import scatter_matrix

iris = datasets.load_iris()
iris_df = pd.DataFrame(iris['data'], columns=iris['feature_names'])
iris_df['species'] = iris['target']

scatter_matrix(iris_df, alpha=0.2, figsize=(10, 10))
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

In our case we were executing below code "`axs = pd.scatter_matrix(sampled_data, figsize=(10, 10))` "

so the error clearly says scatter_matrix is not available in pandas

[image]

**Solution:**
A bit of google and we found scatter_matrix is available in pandas.plotting

So correct code is  "axs = ***pd.plotting.scatter_matrix***(sampled_data, figsize=(10, 10)) "

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I used

```
from pandas.plotting import scatter_matrix
```

and called `scatter_matrix` directly worked like charm.