# Display pandas dataframe using custom style inside function in IPython

Tags: python, pandas, ipython, jupyter, pandas-styles

In a jupyter notebook, I have a function which prepares the input features and targets matrices for a tensorflow model.

Inside this function, I would like to display a correlation matrix with a background gradient to better see the strongly correlated features.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50703596/5380294) answer shows how to do that exactly how I want to do it. The problem is that from the inside of a function I cannot get any output, i.e. this:

```
def display_corr_matrix_custom():
    rs = np.random.RandomState(0)
    df = pd.DataFrame(rs.rand(10, 10))
    corr = df.corr()
    corr.style.background_gradient(cmap='coolwarm')

display_corr_matrix_custom()
```

clearly does not show anything. Normally, I use IPython's `display.display()` function. In this case, however, I cannot use it since I want to retain my custom background.

Is there another way to display this matrix (if possible, without `matplotlib`) without returning it?

---

EDIT: Inside my real function, I also display other stuff (as data description) and I would like to display the correlation matrix at a precise location. Furthermore, my function returns many dataframes, so returning the matrix as proposed by @brentertainer does not directly display the matrix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mostly have it. Two changes:

- Get the Styler object based from `corr`.
- Display the `styler` in the function using IPython's `display.display()`

```
def display_corr_matrix_custom():
    rs = np.random.RandomState(0)
    df = pd.DataFrame(rs.rand(10, 10))
    corr = df.corr()  # corr is a DataFrame
    styler = corr.style.background_gradient(cmap='coolwarm')  # styler is a Styler
    display(styler)  # using Jupyter's display() function

display_corr_matrix_custom()
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Actually, I'm looking for a solution different than returning it (if possible). I've edited my question with further details.

Comment: @David Have you tried displaying the styler from inside the function? Try doing that instead of returning the styler. I see you have copied code from the link you posted. That code won't work as you expect because it was meant to run as a script, not in the scope of a function.

Comment: oh, my bad! I definitely had to think more about what I was doing. I assumed that the style was somehow modified inplace in the df, but clearly pandas df does not embed a style (hence, `display.display(corr) does not displayed what I wanted). Displaying the styler indeed works! Thanks!

Comment: @David  Great! I have amended my response.