# Save correlation matrix into png image

Tags: python, dataframe

I used `corr`python's method to view the correlation matrix of my dataset.Considering that it was too big,I could not see it all at a time,I had to scroll left and right to see it.So,I tried to save it as an image but it failed giving me this error

> 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'savefig'

This is the code I wrote :

```
path_to_file = "C:\\Users\\hmk\\Desktop\\Final.csv"
data = pd.read_csv(path_to_file)
corr = data.corr()
corr.style.background_gradient(cmap='coolwarm')
corr.savefig('result.png', bbox_inches='tight', pad_inches=0.0)
```

Comment: Take a look at this link about storing pandas dataframes as images https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35634238/how-to-save-a-pandas-dataframe-table-as-a-png

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Plot correlation matrix using pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29432629/plot-correlation-matrix-using-pandas)

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/a/29432741/6372685