# Linear reliance in Linear Regression in Python

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, seaborn

How to check linear reliance between dependent variable and independent variables? Because so as to make Linear Regression model in Python we have to use (as I suppose) only variables which are: 1. correlated with dependent variable 2. independent variables which are not correlated with other independent variables 3. independent variables with linear reliance with dependent variables ? 
Please give me the code which is able to chech linear reliance in Python

Comment: Your question is not very clear, but if you use Pandas you can try function corr() to check correlations between all valiables in dataset: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.corr.html

Comment: You can also check this topic: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29432629/plot-correlation-matrix-using-pandas

Answer (score 0):

You can use pandas for that:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'feature one': [1,2,3,5,2,3],
                   'feature two': [5,10,18,23,16,20],
                   'feature three': [-23,-4,1,29,2,112],
                   'result': [10,20,30,50,20,30]})


print(df)

print(df.corr())
```

You will see that `feature one` has the biggest correlation with result, then `feature two` and then `feature three`. You can also check out the correlation between each feature.

So, for your linear model I would chose first and second feature

If values are close to -1 or 1, that means that there is big correlation between features, if values are close to 0, that means that that there is no correlation.

Comment: taga, so as I mean if values are close to 0 the is NOT a linear reliance between independent variables and dependent variable?

Comment: If values in correlation result are close to 0 , that means that there is no correlation (use classification algorithms).

Comment: but correlation means linear reliance ? taga ?

Comment: Have I answered your question?