# How to plot multivariate binary data

Tags: binary, data-visualization, visualization, pca, binary-data

I have a dataset of 78 variables which the input data of all the variables are binary (0 and 1). I want to plot the data in one graph. originally I plan to plot in PCA, but I think it won't work since PCA required numerical input data (is it?). Any suggestions what kind of data visualization to be used for this type of data? Thank you very much.
I do python and R.

Comment: Did you try to plot a [correlation heatmap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29432629/plot-correlation-matrix-using-pandas)?  The easiest way uses Seaborn (see the third linked answer).

Comment: About your question concerning PCA, [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/) is a more appropriate forum. For example [Can principal component analysis be applied to datasets containing a mix of continuous and categorical variables?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/5774/can-principal-component-analysis-be-applied-to-datasets-containing-a-mix-of-cont) and [Doing principal component analysis or factor analysis on binary data](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/16331/doing-principal-component-analysis-or-factor-analysis-on-binary-data).