# How to display uncorrelated columns using python code without plotting

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, machine-learning, statistics

I have a DataFrame where some columns are columns are correlated and some are not. I want to display only the uncorrelated columns as output. can anyone help me out in solving this.I dont want to plot but display the uncorrelated column names.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Plot correlation matrix using pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29432629/plot-correlation-matrix-using-pandas)

Comment: I want to display the column names which are uncorrelated rather than plotting.

Answer (score 0):

First of all calculate the correlation:

```
import pandas as pd
myDataFrame=pd.DataFrame(data)

correl=myDataFrame.corr()
```

Define what you mean by "uncorrelated". I will use an absolute value of 0.5 here

```
uncor_level=0.5
```

The following code will give you the names of the pairs that are uncorrelated

```
pairs=np.full([len(correl)**2,2],None) #define an empty array to store the results
z=0
for x in range(0,len(correl)): #loop for each row(index)

    for y in range(0,len(correl)): #loop for each column

        if abs(correl.iloc[x,y])<uncor_level:

            pair=[correl.index[x],correl.columns[y]]
            pairs[z]=pair
            z=z+1
```