# Seaborn showing scientific notation in heatmap for 3-digit numbers

Tags: python, seaborn, heatmap, plot-annotations

I'm creating a heatmap from a pandas pivot_table as below:

```
table2 = pd.pivot_table(df,values='control',columns='Year',index='Region',aggfunc=np.sum)
sns.heatmap(table2,annot=True,cmap='Blues')
```

It creates a heat map as shown below. You can see the numbers are not huge (max 750), but it's showing them in scientific notation. If I view the table itself this is not the case. Any idea on how I could get it to show the numbers in plain notation?

[image: Heatmap]

Answer (score 338, accepted):

According to the [docs](http://stanford.edu/%7Emwaskom/software/seaborn/generated/seaborn.heatmap.html#seaborn.heatmap), the param `fmt='.2g'` is being applied because you've set `annot=True` so you can modify the format being applied to:

```
sns.heatmap(table2,annot=True,cmap='Blues', fmt='g')
```

Comment: You can also use `fmt='d'` if your values are integers like this: `sns.heatmap(table2, annot=True, cmap='Blues', fmt='d')`

Comment: For floats with two decimal places, it's `.2f`. See https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html?highlight=string#formatspec for more options.

Answer (score 9):

According to the [docs](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.heatmap.html), the parameter `fmt` is set to `.2g` when `annot=True`. So, for example, if your data is `float`, you can use:

```
sns.heatmap(table2, annot=True, cmap='Blues', fmt='.3g')
```

By that, you're telling python to show 3 significant figures. To understand the "fmt" better, check out this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65020192/4529605

Answer (score 1):

For "big integer numbers" I am big fan of `fmt=',d'` for the Thousands Separators:

```py
sns.heatmap(table2, annot=True, cmap='Blues', fmt=',d')
```