# How to avoid scientific notation when annotating a seaborn heatmap

Tags: python, seaborn, heatmap, plot-annotations

I have a dataframe that contains percentages. If I use seaborn to make a [clusterplot](http://stanford.edu/~mwaskom/software/seaborn/examples/structured_heatmap.html) somehow the number `100` is plotted as `1+e01`.

Is there any way to avoid this?

I tried rounding the percentages before plotting them, but that does not affect the plot.

Answer (score 6):

Use `fmt="d"`, as in [this example](http://stanford.edu/~mwaskom/software/seaborn/examples/heatmap_annotation.html):

```
import seaborn as sns
sns.set()

flights_long = sns.load_dataset("flights")
flights = flights_long.pivot("month", "year", "passengers")
flights = flights.reindex(flights_long.iloc[:12].month)

sns.heatmap(flights, annot=True, fmt="d")
```

[image]

`fmt` is a parameter to `heatmap` but additional `clustermap` kwargs are passed through to the main heatmap.

Comment: Is there another way than using `"d"`? I'm having trouble with numpy's float arrays. I want to avoid using `array.astype(int)` if possbile, because I want `nan` values to not be displayed in the heat map. EDIT: Ok, I found out that [`"g"`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29648332/7669319) works