# Heat Maps Seaborn Annot Error

Tags: python, matplotlib, annotations, seaborn

As extension to my previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31069153/bubble-plot-or-heatmap-in-matplotlib/31077694#31077694)

With same data set I am not able to get the annotation done.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
sns.set()

df = pd.read_csv('heat_map_data.csv')

df3 = df.copy()
for c in ['Place','Name']:
    df3[c] = df3[c].astype('category')

sns.heatmap(df3.pivot_table(index='Place', columns='Name', values='00:00:00', annot=True) )

plt.show()
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "heatmap_sns.py", line 13, in <module>
    sns.heatmap(df3.pivot_table(index='Place', columns='Name', values='00:00:00', annot=True) )
TypeError: pivot_table() got an unexpected keyword argument 'annot'
```

Please suggest what could be the fix ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`annot=True` is an argument of `heatmap`, not `pivot_table`:

```
sns.heatmap(df3.pivot_table(index='Place', columns='Name', values='00:00:00'), 
            annot=True)
```