# How to set float values as scientific notation in matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib, flask, list-comprehension, seaborn

I've in `seaborn` the following *float* results:

```
[7.4e-05, 7.4e-05, 7.4e-05, 7.4e-05, 7.4e-05, 7.4e-05, 7.4e-05, 7.4e-05, 7.3e-05, 7.4e-05, 7.3e-05, 7.4e-05, 7.4e-05, 7.4e-05, 7.4e-05, 7.4e-05, 7.4e-05, 7.4e-05, 7.4e-05, 7.4e-05, 7.3e-05, 7.4e-05, 7.4e-05, 7.4e-05, 7.4e-05, 7.4e-05, 7.4e-05, 7.4e-05, 7.4e-05, 7.4e-05, 7.4e-05, 7.4e-05, 7.3e-05, 7.4e-05, 7.4e-05, 7.4e-05, 7.4e-05, 7.4e-05, 7.4e-05, 7.4e-05, 7.4e-05, 7.4e-05, 7.4e-05, 7.4e-05, 7.4e-05, 7.4e-05, 7.4e-05, 7.4e-05, 7.4e-05, 7.4e-05, 7.4e-05, 7.4e-05, 7.4e-05, 7.4e-05, 7.4e-05, 7.4e-05]
```

Plotting me a graph with the scientific notation disabled as you can see:

[image: Plot from list]

The result function:

```
def result(values, time):
    x = 0.000000000001
    max = 0.000000001
    min = 0.001
    y = [(1.0*i*(max/min) for i in values]
    return generate((y, time))
```

And the function who generate the graph:

```
def generate(data_):
    data, time = data_
    img = StringIO.StringIO()
    sns.set_style("darkgrid")
    plt.plot(time, data)
    plt.savefig(img, format=format_)
    img.seek(0)
    x = base64.b64encode(img.getvalue())
    return x
```

The following sources tell me that `seaborn` by default set the values in scientific notation. But in this case I'm having float results.

[Seaborn showing scientific notation in heatmap for 3-digit numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29647749/seaborn-showing-scientific-notation-in-heatmap-for-3-digit-numbers)

[Prevent scientific notation in seaborn boxplot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33804658/prevent-scientific-notation-in-seaborn-boxplot)

[How to prevent numbers being changed to exponential form in Python matplotlib figure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14711655/how-to-prevent-numbers-being-changed-to-exponential-form-in-python-matplotlib-fi)

[How to avoid scientific notation when annotating a seaborn clustermap?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31055302/how-to-avoid-scientific-notation-when-annotating-a-seaborn-clustermap)

Do float results matters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `matplotlib.ticker.FormatStrFormatter` solved the problem

```
import matplotlib.ticker as mtick

def generate(data_):
    data, time = data_
    img = StringIO.StringIO()
    sns.set_style("darkgrid")
    plt.plot(time, data)
    plt.gca().yaxis.set_major_formatter(mtick.FormatStrFormatter('%.1E')) #this line solves the problem
    plt.savefig(img, format=format_)
    img.seek(0)
    x = base64.b64encode(img.getvalue())
    return x
```

Using another *time* and *values* I got this plot, with the yaxis in scientific notation.

[image]

See here the [documentation](http://matplotlib.org/api/ticker_api.html#matplotlib.ticker.FormatStrFormatter)

> class matplotlib.ticker.FormatStrFormatter(fmt)
>
> ```
> Bases: matplotlib.ticker.Formatter
>
> Use an old-style (‘%’ operator) format string to format the tick
> ```

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with `flask`, but I think you problem may be in plotting, not something else. Let's strip away all other stuff, leave only the plot. I reduced your code to this:

```
import datetime
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

import seaborn as sns
sns.set_style("darkgrid")

import numpy as np
%matplotlib inline

def generate(data_):
    data, time = data_
    plt.plot(time, data)

def result(values, time):
    x = 0.000000000001
    max = 0.000000001
    min = 0.001
    y = [ 1.0*i*(max/min) for i in values ]
    return generate((y, time))

values = [7.4e-05, 7.4e-05, 7.4e-05, 7.4e-05, 7.4e-05, 7.4e-05, 
          7.4e-05, 7.4e-05, 7.3e-05, 7.4e-05, 7.3e-05, 7.4e-05, 
          7.4e-05, 7.4e-05, 7.4e-05, 7.4e-05, 7.4e-05, 7.4e-05, 
          7.4e-05, 7.4e-05, 7.3e-05, 7.4e-05, 7.4e-05, 7.4e-05, 
          7.4e-05, 7.4e-05, 7.4e-05, 7.4e-05, 7.4e-05, 7.4e-05, 
          7.4e-05, 7.4e-05, 7.3e-05, 7.4e-05, 7.4e-05, 7.4e-05, 
          7.4e-05, 7.4e-05, 7.4e-05, 7.4e-05, 7.4e-05, 7.4e-05, 
          7.4e-05, 7.4e-05, 7.4e-05, 7.4e-05, 7.4e-05, 7.4e-05, 
          7.4e-05, 7.4e-05, 7.4e-05, 7.4e-05, 7.4e-05, 7.4e-05, 
          7.4e-05, 7.4e-05]

time = [datetime.time(17, 44, 41), datetime.time(17, 45, 41), 
        datetime.time(17, 46, 41), datetime.time(17, 47, 41), 
        datetime.time(17, 48, 41), datetime.time(17, 49, 41), 
        datetime.time(17, 50, 41), datetime.time(17, 51, 41), 
        datetime.time(17, 52, 41), datetime.time(17, 53, 41), 
        datetime.time(17, 54, 41), datetime.time(17, 55, 41), 
        datetime.time(17, 56, 41), datetime.time(17, 57, 41), 
        datetime.time(17, 58, 41), datetime.time(17, 59, 41), 
        datetime.time(18, 0, 41), datetime.time(18, 1, 41), 
        datetime.time(18, 2, 41), datetime.time(18, 3, 41), 
        datetime.time(18, 4, 41), datetime.time(18, 5, 41), 
        datetime.time(18, 6, 41), datetime.time(18, 7, 41), 
        datetime.time(18, 8, 41), datetime.time(18, 9, 41), 
        datetime.time(18, 10, 41), datetime.time(18, 11, 41), 
        datetime.time(18, 12, 41), datetime.time(18, 13, 41), 
        datetime.time(18, 14, 41), datetime.time(18, 15, 41), 
        datetime.time(18, 16, 41), datetime.time(18, 17, 41), 
        datetime.time(18, 18, 54), datetime.time(18, 19, 55), 
        datetime.time(18, 20, 57), datetime.time(18, 21, 57), 
        datetime.time(18, 23, 3), datetime.time(18, 24, 27), 
        datetime.time(18, 25, 27), datetime.time(18, 26, 27), 
        datetime.time(18, 27, 27), datetime.time(18, 28, 27), 
        datetime.time(18, 29, 27), datetime.time(18, 30, 38), 
        datetime.time(18, 32, 4), datetime.time(18, 33, 12), 
        datetime.time(18, 34, 54), datetime.time(18, 35, 54), 
        datetime.time(18, 37, 34), datetime.time(18, 38, 34), 
        datetime.time(18, 40, 28), datetime.time(18, 41, 28), 
        datetime.time(18, 42, 28), datetime.time(18, 43, 28)]

result(values,time)
```

And it gives me result with scientific notation:

[image: scientific notation by default]

Try this code and see if makes scientific notation or not. If not, my bet is you need to update `matplotlib` and `seaborn` to the last version. If it does, at least you know that something else is screwing up your labels.