# How to understand Seaborn's heatmap annotation format

Tags: python, seaborn, heatmap, plot-annotations

I am looking for a way to show "0.0045" as "0.45%" on `seaboarn`'s heatmap by specifying the `fmt` keyword:

```
sns.heatmap(data, annot=True, fmt='??')
```

However, I did not find a list of format to use. Searching between different examples, I have seen "d", ".2g", ".1f", ".1f%". But it is not clear what is the convention we are assuming here.

Is this assuming people have a common understanding of the formatting format? Or this is present on a doc page I missed?

Comment: The code is `annotation = ("{:" + self.fmt + "}").format(val)`, so start with [pyformat.info](https://pyformat.info/)

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You can use `.2%` as the `fmt` to have your annotations displayed as percentages with 2 decimal places. Following is a minimum complete example. I have divided by 100 to have numbers in the range you are interested in

---

```
import numpy as np; np.random.seed(0)
import seaborn as sns; sns.set()
uniform_data = np.random.rand(6, 6)/100
ax = sns.heatmap(uniform_data,annot=True, fmt=".2%")
```

[image]

Answer (score 61):

There isn't a clear and quick answer to this at the top of search engine results so I provide simple examples here:

`.1e` = scientific notation with 1 decimal point (standard form)

`.2f` = 2 decimal places

`.3g` = 3 significant figures

`.4%` = percentage with 4 decimal places

A more detailed explanation on the python string formatter can be found here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html?highlight=string#formatspec (scroll down to table with e, E, f, F, etc. in the Type column)

Answer (score 2):

I used .1f as the format specifier

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10,10))   
sns.heatmap(df.corr(),annot=True,fmt=".1f",ax=ax)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

In case you did not know, .1g does not refer to the decimal places, but instead refers to the number of significant figures.