# Create a heatmap using python

Tags: python, numpy, graph, scipy

I've a very simple csv which is in-fact a a matrix

```
row/data, field_1, field_2, field_3
row_1, 223, 231, 5454 
row_2, 4545, 4343, 23423
row_3, 3433, 325454, 34343
```

I would like to generate a heatmap in python with the axis labels being the field names and the rows names.

What is the recommended library to use for that task?

Comment: Asking for tool recommendations is off-topic for SO, but you would probably benefit from looking at matplotlib/seaborn.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [python Making heatmap from DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12286607/python-making-heatmap-from-dataframe)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

we can use [seaborn.heatmap](http://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.heatmap.html) method:

```
In [28]: import seaborn as sns

In [29]: df
Out[29]:
  row/data  field_1  field_2  field_3
0    row_1      223      231     5454
1    row_2     4545     4343    23423
2    row_3     3433   325454    34343

In [30]: sns.heatmap(df.set_index('row/data'), annot=True, fmt='g')
Out[30]: <matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot at 0xc839358>
```

yields:

[image]

or transposed:

```
In [32]: sns.heatmap(df.set_index('row/data').T, annot=True, fmt='g')
Out[32]: <matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot at 0xc341470>
```

[image]

---

- first check [Pandas Visualization online docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/visualization.html) - whether it can cover your needs.
- `seaborn` module is pretty useful when working with Pandas data sets - check [seaborn gallery](http://seaborn.pydata.org/examples/) - it has couple of methods, that are not implemented in Pandas
- Another greate visualization module is [bokeh](http://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/gallery.html), especially when we need to produce HTML reports.
- And the last but not least - [plot.ly](https://plot.ly/r/shiny-gallery/) - great online visualization tool.

Comment: I think he/she asked what are the reasons behind your recommendation. It would be more constructive. Moreover, there are a lot of posts explaining how to create a heatmap with python.

Comment: @ManelFornos, thanks for your comment! I've added a few words about different "visualization" modules...