# How do I make a heatmap with seaborn module in python using the pandas dataframe given below?

Tags: python, seaborn

[image: python pandas dataframe representation in notepad]

This is a dataframe of countries and the count of cars each country has.
It's preferred to have countries on the left/y axis and cars as bottom/x axis.

Comment: Did you try this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12286607/making-heatmap-from-pandas-dataframe

Comment: Kindly refer to this.[seaborn.heatmap](http://alanpryorjr.com/visualizations/seaborn/heatmap/heatmap/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply set the index as `country` and plot the heatmap via `sns.heatmap`.
Here is the code:

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df=pd.DataFrame({'country':['us','france','spain','italy','germany'],
                 'corvette':[2,0,2,11,0],
                 'ford':[0,1,10,0,10],
                 'toyota':[1,10,0,1,1]})
df.set_index(['country'],inplace=True)
print(df) #1
ax=sns.heatmap(df,cmap='coolwarm')
plt.show() #2
```

OUTPUT: #1

```
         corvette  ford  toyota
country
us              2     0       1
france          0     1      10
spain           2    10       0
italy          11     0       1
germany         0    10       1
```

OUTPUT: #2
[image]

Comment: What does setiting inplace equal to True do?

Comment: It performs the operation on the df inplace so that you don't have to assign it back to df again. `df=df.set_index(['col'])` is equivalent to `df.set_index(['col'], inplace=True)`