# Is there a specific chart that can be used to plot this type of data?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

I have this data

```
Zip Codes  Year     Mean
2443       2016    92.869565
           2017    93.364486
           2018    93.070000
           2019    93.760000
2445       2016    94.848837
                     ...    
27326      2019    99.000000
27334      2016    94.250000
           2017    95.625000
           2018    96.812500
           2019    97.666667
```

i have the above dataframe from pandas, which has about 1000 zip codes for 4 different years for each zipcode and a mean value of the height of a specific plant.

What is the best possible way to represent this data ?

Comment: How about filling in the map with the average data for the year, and then creating four graphs for four years? I propose to draw four years in [this example](https://plotly.com/python/mapbox-county-choropleth/).

Answer (score 1):

Use a heat map ([`seaborn.heatmap`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.heatmap.html)) with zip codes on rows, years on columns, and cell color by mean plant height.

**SEE ALSO:**
[Plotting a 2D heatmap with Matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33282368/967621)
[Making heatmap from pandas DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12286607/967621)
[The Python Graph Gallery: Heatmap](https://python-graph-gallery.com/heatmap/)