# Swap axis Seaborn heatmap python

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn, heatmap, axis

I have the data frame h3_Ho_Hm which looks like this with hour as index.

```
        KE      EH          LA          PR
Hour                
15      0.01052 0.010545    0.010325    0.013201
30      0.01052 0.010545    0.010325    0.013201
45      0.01052 0.010545    0.010932    0.013201
100     0.01052 0.010545    0.010932    0.009901
115     0.01052 0.010545    0.010932    0.013201
------------------------------------------------
2245    0.01021 0.010252    0.010325    0.006601
2300    0.01021 0.010252    0.010021    0.009901
2315    0.01021 0.010252    0.010325    0.009901
2330    0.01021 0.010252    0.009718    0.009901
2345    0.01021 0.010252    0.010325    NaN
```

I want to create a heatmap which shows the columns on the y-axis and the hour column on the x-axis. I tried to use the code from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12286607/making-heatmap-from-pandas-dataframe) post which I implemented as so

```
Index = temp1[0] (a column with the hours)
Cols = ["KE", "EH", "LA", "PR"]
h3_heatmap = DataFrame(data = h3_Ho_Hm, index = Index, columns = Cols)

sns.heatmap(h3_heatmap)
```

Which give me this result

[image: Heatmap]

When I use the code below I get a nice result but still with the wrong axis order

```
sns.heatmap(h3_Ho_Hm)
```

[image: Heatmap2]

Any idea on how I can swap the axis so that the KE, EH, LA and PR are on the y-axis and the hours on the x-axis?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the transposed dataframe:

```py
sns.heatmap(h3_Ho_Hm.T)
```

Comment: This works, thank you! I tried to transpose it as well with h3_Ho_Hm.transpose() but that didn't work. Glad your solution did work!

Comment: I don't know why `h3_Ho_Hm.transpose()` didn't work. It should give the same result as `h3_Ho_Hm.T`.