# Color dataframe cell backgrounds according to value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, heatmap, pandas-styles

I'm trying to create a heatmap from a pandas dataframe like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12286607/making-heatmap-from-pandas-dataframe), except instead of using the pd df to make an mpl plot, I want to "superimpose" that heatmap as the cell background colors.

How would I go about doing this such that the color map is continuous from values 0 to 1, or continuous from the minimum value in the df to the maximum value?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Something like [Background Gradient and Text Gradient](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/style.html#Background-Gradient-and-Text-Gradient)? The [third answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50605020/15497888) covers this option. Some sample data and expected output would be beneficial in order to differentiate the answers from the linked question and what you're looking for.

Comment: Just what I was looking for, thank you Henry. Sorry, I don't use Pandas for formatting much!

Answer (score 0):

Use [background_gradient()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.io.formats.style.Styler.background_gradient.html), as mentioned by Henry Ecker