# How to create a heatmap of Pandas dataframe in Python

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to create a heatmap and I am following the following question:

[Making heatmap from pandas DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12286607/making-heatmap-from-pandas-dataframe)

My dataframe looks like the following picture:

[image]

I tried the following code:

```
years = ["1860","1870", "1880","1890","1900","1910","1920","1930","1940","1950","1960","1970","1980","1990","2000"]
kantons = ["AG","AI","AR","BE","BL","BS","FR","GE","GL","GR","JU","LU","NE","NW","OW","SG","SH","SO","SZ","TG","TI","UR","VD","VS","ZG","ZH"]
   
df = pd(abs(dfYears), index=years, columns=kantons)
```

which gives the exception that:

> "AG" can not be used as float

So I thought if I need to drop the index column which is not possible.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When replicating similar data, you can do:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

years = ["1860","1870", "1880","1890","1900","1910","1920","1930","1940","1950","1960","1970","1980","1990","2000"]
kantons = ["AG","AI","AR","BE","BL","BS","FR","GE","GL","GR","JU","LU","NE","NW","OW","SG","SH","SO","SZ","TG","TI","UR","VD","VS","ZG","ZH"]
   
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(low=10000, high=200000, size=(15, 26)), index=years, columns=kantons)
df.style.background_gradient(cmap='Reds')
```

Pandas has some [Builtin Styles](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/style.html#Builtin-Styles) for the most common visualization needs. [`.background_gradient`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.io.formats.style.Styler.background_gradient.html) function is a simple way for highlighting cells based on their values. `cmap` parameter determines the color map based on the `matplotlib` [colormaps](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/color/colormap_reference.html).