# 3D Heatmap Plot of a data frame from .csv file

Tags: python, heatmap

I am trying to plot a 3d heat map from a csv file with the first row being the y axis and the first colum being the x axis and everything else is the z-values. The problem I am facing is to define the x,y and z from the .csv file ( I have more entries than the ones I have taken picture of)
I appreciate the help in advance
[Example how the csv file looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CHcuV.png)

Comment: Example for matplotlib library is [here](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/images_contours_and_fields/pcolor_demo.html#sphx-glr-gallery-images-contours-and-fields-pcolor-demo-py).

Comment: This question is duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12286607/9705687)